# What is the most common word for medicine? (the physical substances, not the field of study)

Tags: word-choice

医学 「いがく」 seems to be the field of medicine

医術 「いじゅつ」 might be another word for the field of medicine?

薬 「くすり」 is the word I found listed most often.

However, I also saw 医薬 「いやく」 and 薬剤 「やくざい」 but don't know what the differences between these words are.

Comment: 医学 is いがく. Also, although most can be used as meaning medicine, 薬 is generally the most popular/casual one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No comparison; Go with 「薬{くすり}」 or 「お薬」 as a patient or someone on the patient's side.  It is hard to beat kun-yomi words in intuitiveness.

「医薬」 and 「薬剤」 are too technical/academic for everyday conversations unless you are a medical professional.

「医学」 and 「医術」 do not even mean 「薬」 in the first place.  Those words refer to the study/field of Medicine.